# Does Controller.OnException get called before ExceptionFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to understand the MVC pipeline here:

It seems that the order is like so:

1. AuthorizationFilters
2. OnActionExecuting
3. ActionExecutes
4. OnActionExecuted
5. OnResultExecuting
6. Create the action result
7. OnResultExecuted
8. Write to response stream

When does the [Controller.OnException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) run relative to the [ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.exceptionfilterattribute.onexception%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably documented somewhere, in the source at least, but I just ran this little experiment:

```
// in MyHandleErrorAttribute, globally configured
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Debug.Print("HandleErrorAttribute.OnException 1");
    base.OnException(filterContext);
    Debug.Print("HandleErrorAttribute.OnException 2");
}

...

// in HomeController
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Debug.Print("Controller OnException 1");
    base.OnException(filterContext);
    Debug.Print("Controller OnException 2");
}
```

and the Output Window shows:

> HandleErrorAttribute.OnException 1
>   HandleErrorAttribute.OnException 2
>   Controller OnException 1
>   Controller OnException 2